# CSS Panel Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s7xp1amg/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #CEECF5;">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul id="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">p</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">e</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">r</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">r</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">o</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sortable {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
#sortable li {
    margin: -8px 8px 3px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    _float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(" #sortable ").sortable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "window"
    });
});
```

When you go to move one of the letter tiles in the JSFiddle results area, the whole panel area 'expands' on click and the tile moves up vertically. Then when you drop the tile it 'retracts'. Any ideas on how to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the attribute:

```
float: left;
```

to `li` elements prevents that.

However, if you want the tiles centered then some things need to be modified:

1 - in html, the list will be embeeded now in a table.

2 - in css, the `ul` element lose the `width: 100%`

3 - in css, declare `margin: auto` for element `table`

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/s7xp1amg/12/

Comment: Any thoughts on how to both keep the tiles centered horizontally and avoid the issues described in the question.

Comment: Check my answer, I included that.

Answer (score 0):

Either add:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

or float both the parent and the list items.